# Ubuntu updating stopped while processing apt-get update

Tags: apt, updates

Ubuntu updating stopped while processing `apt-get update`:

```
...

Ign https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com trusty Release<br>
Ign https://private-ppa.launchpad.net trusty Release<br>
100% [Working]
```

It remains such this for 15 minutes. Should I wait or is it a bug?

Comment: try with disabling  all third party ppa and changing your update server and let us know if problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a bug. Just do <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> followed by `fg`.